# When I click on the new 'About Us' link in the help down drop menu, it gives me a page not found

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I click on the new 'About Us' link, it gives me this page:

[image]

> ## Page Not Found
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested.

Why?

Comment: Confirmed: I see the same effect. Probably because the link is to `http://scifi.stackexchange.com/company/about`, an SFF page rather than an SE-central page.

Comment: Looks like an old link left over from the company name change. The "About Us" link at the bottom of the page points to `http://stackoverflow.com/company/about` and goes to the right page. This is the same on all the other sites, so you should post this on the main meta.

Comment: @Null done. ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276002/175002) on the main meta:

> We caught this shortly after we shipped too, so it's been fixed. You reported it riiiight in between.